# Periodically redraw QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have created a custom QML Element by extending QQuickItem and overriding the updatePaintNode() function.

Since I need to draw rectangles along a timeline which will grow in real-time I need the GUI to be redrawn for every new frame.

Is there a way to have the updatePaintNode() function be executed periodically for every new frame?

I have tried calling `node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyForceUpdate)` which did not cause the updatePaintNode() function to be called periodically.

**Edit: this is what my code looks like:**

```
QSGNode *PianoRoll::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *n, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *data)
{
    QSGGeometryNode *node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(n);
    if (!node)
    {
        node = new QSGSimpleRectNode(boundingRect(), Qt::white);
    }

    node->removeAllChildNodes();

    qreal msPerScreen = 10000;
    qreal pitchesPerScreen = 128;
    qreal x_factor = (qreal) boundingRect().width() / msPerScreen;
    qreal y_factor = (qreal) boundingRect().height() / pitchesPerScreen;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_stream->notes.size(); i++)
    {
        shared_ptr<Note> note = m_stream->notes.at(i);
        qreal left = boundingRect().left() + note->getTime() * x_factor;
        qreal top = boundingRect().top() + note->getPitch() * y_factor;
        qreal width;
        qreal height = y_factor;

        if (note->getDuration() != 0)
        {
            width = note->getDuration() * x_factor;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO
            width = 500 * x_factor;

        }

        QRectF noteRectangle = QRectF(left, top, width, height);
        node->appendChildNode(new QSGSimpleRectNode(noteRectangle, Qt::black));
    }
    node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyForceUpdate);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, make sure the code runs on the right node. It's supposed to work./

Comment: I added my code to the post, maybe you can help me out!

Comment: You need to have QQuickItem::ItemHasContents set. Have you created a timer that periodically calls update()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of `updatePaintNode`:

> The function is called as a result of `QQuickItem::update()`, if the user has set the `QQuickItem::ItemHasContents` flag on the item.

You need to be doing both things: calling `update()` periodically, and having the flag set. That's all there's to it.

If you need a source of ticks for `update()`, you want the `QQuickWindow::frameSwapped()` or a similar signal. This gets emitted every frame, and exactly every frame. So, this would work:

```
QSGNode * myNode = ...;

QObject::connect(window, &QQuickWindow::frameSwapped, [=](){ myNode->update(); });
```

Comment: Setting up a timer to invoke update() every couple of seconds seemed to be trouble-prone to me, that´s why I was supposing there was a mechanism to handle fluid repainting (ie automatically calling update for ever frame that is drawn).

Comment: Strangely, this "frameSwapped" signal does not work for me. When my application starts it is emitted once, scene is painted and then "update" is never called again.

Comment: Also doesn't work if I call update manually, I just see no effect, although I set ItemHasContents to true.

Comment: In more recent Qt they may have optimized the frame swap out if there's literally nothing to be done to the scene. You can investigate whether calling `update()` within `updatePaintNode()` would do the trick. Perhaps it'll only update in the *next* frame - exactly what you wish.

Comment: There is a string in the source code in `qtdeclarative/src/quick/scenegraph/qsgthreadedrenderloop.cpp`: "Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()".